# почему после $.get запроса не срабатывает скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

$.post("page.php""})...... в файле page.php alert("sucsses")

$(element).innerHTML = data; не срабатывает

$(element).html(data); а через jquery срабатывает

вопрос почему так

Comment: [HTML.innerHTML vs Jquery.html() - Javascript execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584931/2881286)

Comment: что именно находится в `page.php`? `alert("...")` или `<script>alert("...")</script>`?

Comment: да <script>alert("...")</script>

Comment: Написал ответ, если нужно, можно расписать подробно как именно jquery выдирает скрипты и выполняет

Answer (score 0):

Согласно спецификации html элементы `<script>` вставленные с помощью [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations) не должны исполняться.

При этом, метод [`.html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) в `jquery` вырезает все теги `<script>` из переданной строки и вставляет их отдельно - именно поэтому код в них выполняется.